# Send coreData by Email

Tags: core-data, core-data-migration

I've made a simple app to store locations with CoreLocation in CoreData. My Problem is that now i want to send all my "data Base" (CoreData) by email to see and treat the data but i can't do it. I tried to convert NSManagedObjects into a NSDictionary and enumerate that dictionary but it always came null. what should i do?

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
   NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
   id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
    context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
   }
return context;
}


NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"RegistoCoreData"];
self.locations = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];

[self.tableView reloadData];


- (IBAction)send:(id)sender {

NSArray *keys = [[[location entity]attributesByName]allKeys];
dicionarioLocalizacoesNoCoreData = [location dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:keys];

for (NSString *valores in dicionarioLocalizacoesNoCoreData){

    NSLog(@"%@, %@", valores, [dicionarioLocalizacoesNoCoreData objectForKey:valores]);  
}

// Email Subject
NSString *emailTitle = @"Localizações";
// Email Content
NSString *messageBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@",valores, [dicionarioLocalizacoesNoCoreData objectForKey:valores]];
// To address
NSArray *toRecipents = @[@"email@mail.com"];

MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[mc setSubject:emailTitle];
[mc setMessageBody:messageBody isHTML:NO];
[mc setToRecipients:toRecipents];

// Present mail view controller on screen
[self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

}

Comment: *"...i want to send all my "data Base" (CoreData) by email to see and treat the data..."* So this is just for your own use, to inspect and edit the data? Or is it a feature that will be in the app when it's complete?

Comment: It's Just for my own use yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mentioned in a comment that this is only for you to inspect the data, using email is an unnecessarily complicated way to approach the problem. Xcode can download any of your app's data to your Mac. Go to the Organizer window (cmd-shift-2), select your device, and then the "Applications" entry for the device. That will list all apps installed via Xcode. There's a "Download" link at the bottom of the page you can use to get any of the data you want.

If you really want to use email, there are a number of places this code might be going wrong. You should use Xcode's debugger to step through the code. Some possibilities include:

- The fetch request doesn't return any values
- You're assigning the result of the fetch to `self.locations`, but later on you try to send `location`. It's not clear from your question where (if anywhere) `location` gets a value.
- It's not clear where the fetch code comes from-- you don't show it in a method. Maybe the fetch hasn't occurred yet when you try to send the data?

On a somewhat related note: Calling `performSelector` in the first part of this code makes no sense. You might be thinking of `respondsToSelector`, which would make a little sense. Looking up the context on the app delegate isn't great design, but calling `performSelector` like you do does nothing useful for you here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i will try to download the data via Xcode than, I didn't knew that Xcode had that feature. thank's a lot.